# Google Chrome грузит процессор ноутбука под 100%. Что мне делать?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome грузит процессор ноутбука под 100%. Я недавно переехал на SSD и на нём тоже Chrome грузит ЦП также. До этого на HDD также грузил.
Я искал вредоносное ПО средствами Хрома и копался в диспетчере задач и в диспетчере задач Хрома.
Что мне делать?
Ноутбук Asus X540NA
Проц Intel Celeron N3450
ОЗУ 4гб
Windows 10 Enterprise 64gb

Comment: Не использовать google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может ты поймал вирус - майнер, видюху не грузит? Снеси винду и поставь снова, и поставь chrome на чистую винду, образ винды используй нормальный ток, а то слышал, что есть чуваки, которые в систему уже вшивают вредоностный софт)
P.S ноут у тебя слабоват, если считать, что 10 забирет прилично ресурсов и chrome ресурсоемкий процесс, но если у тебя постоянно 100% разгрузка ЦП, то это странно.

Comment: На предыдущей винде на HDD такая же ситуация была.
Без Хрома ЦП нормально себя чувствует.
А его можно разогнать? 
Я просто раньше никогда не разгонял процы.

Comment: Можно, но стоит оно того? Из него особо не выжмешь нифига, т.к железо старое, попробуй действительно юзать другие браузеры, chrome славится своей прожерливостью.

Answer (score 1):

Скачай себе regorgonizer. Он помогает отчистить кеши и все что тормозит компьютер. Или же можете установить Мозилу он намного легче. Но минус Мозилы это когда открываешь вкладки больше 10 начинает тормозить.